# Can't set height: 0; to fieldset if legend is available

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

### Background

I have a form with collapsible fieldsets. In this example, each checkbox opens a fieldset with help of Bootstrap-Collapse.

https://codepen.io/vacoxudelpen/full/LYjOryP

### The Odd

The fieldset **with** legend don't (un)collapse smoothly. The fieldset **without** legend is fine.

### The Known

Bootstrap animates the collapse-elements with `overflow: hidden; height: 0;`.

Apparently the browsers don't like to set the fieldset height to actually 0 (zero), if a legend exists.

So the animations runs till only the legend is visible and then show/hide the fieldset.

[image: showcase how Firefox interprets height 0 in this case]

### EDIT: Solution

Rip the legend out of the fieldset with `float`. Solution within the codepen. Thanks @beni-sinca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old topic. `<legend>` elements were always very vague and there were very many browser inconsistencies around `<legend>`.

I funny enough had a similar task once and managed to fix it by floating the legend element and making sure it has the right width.

In your case I think something like this would do the job:

```
legend.col-form-label {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well in my case. I added this solution the the codepen https://codepen.io/vacoxudelpen/pen/LYjOryP